# How can we verify the security of a device?

Tags: hardware, audit

I've recently been experiencing a situation as follows:

How can I understand the IO of an unknown device?

Say, for example, I am gifted a bluetooth speaker. How can I understand its potential for transmission? If it claims to be just a bluetooth speaker, can I verify that it does not also record and transmit audio?

If there is e.g a blackbox device, what are the ways that we can confirm beyond doubt the safety of transmission?

(software and hardware considered)

Comment: Like your other question, this is a little too broad.